# JavaScript - Adding text box values an storing it in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

i need some code corrected. So here is the JS:

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var myTransaction = new Array[];

function processInfo() {
    var myItem = $('item').value;
    var myAmount = parseFloat($('amount').value);
    var myTotal = myItem + ":" + myAmount;

    var myParagraph = $('message');

    myParagraph.innerHTML = myTransaction;


    for (var theTotal in myTransaction) {
        myTransaction += addTogether[theTotal] + "<br>";
    }
}


window.onload = function () {
    $("addbutton").onclick = processInfo;
}
```

and HTML

```
<section>
    <p>Item:
        <input type="text" id="item" size="30">
        <p>Amount:
            <input type="text" id="amount" size="30">
            <p><span id="message">*</span>

                <p>
                    <input type="button" id="addbutton" value="Add Item" onClick="processInfo();">
</section>
```

What i need to do is get the values of the text boxes, and add them together into one variable then have it stored into the array. Then use a for-in loop to concatenate every element in the Array into a one String variable. However, must also stick a 
 tag at the end every value in the String, last thing is place this String in a paragraph at the end of the page.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Safbu/)

Comment: Yes i know i deleted my comment.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. There's no array `addTogether`. First you set `myTransaction` to an empty array (except that's not the correct syntax). Then you put that into `myParagraph.innerHTML`, but that only makes sense if it contains a string. Then you loop over the empty array, and assign the variable as if it contains a string again. It makes so little sense, I don't know where to start to fix it.

Comment: You say you need to store something in array, but why do you need to do that? Arrays are for repetitive data, but there's only one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you then look at my edition to your code:
If you not understand something with the code so ask me.

At first you forget to close with `;` the function `$`.
then you create array with bad syntax.
third you call addTogether array that doesn't exist.
this is fixed code that i belive working like you asked.

```
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var myTransaction = [];

function processInfo ()
{    
     var myItem = $('item').value;
     var myAmount = parseFloat($('amount').value);
     var myTotal = myItem + ":" + myAmount;
     var myParagraph = $('message');    

     myParagraph.innerHTML = "";
     myTransaction.push(myTotal);
     for (var theTotal in myTransaction)
     {
          myParagraph.innerHTML += myTransaction[theTotal] + "<br>"; 
     }

};

(function () {
    $("addbutton").onclick = processInfo;

})();
```

**Edit**
Mohamed-Ted suggest:
instead of:

```
for (var theTotal in myTransaction)
{
     myParagraph.innerHTML += myTransaction[theTotal] + "<br>"; 
}
```

you can do this:

```
myParagraph.innerHTML += myTransaction.join("<br>");
```

see example on: 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Safbu/3/)

Comment: if you are using the for loop just to concatenate the array elements into a string, you can instead replace it with myParagraph.innerHTML = myTransaction.join("<br>")